# Form action + mail

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, email

What I need is for the user input data from this form (a quiz) to be sent to my mail. However, I am kind of lost. I am using a database to store the questions, possible answers and correct answers, then I'm echoing them as a form. And then, I'm using a different page to evaluate the test and show correct/wrong answers (so the action is already taken). It looks something like this:

```
<form action="./evaluate.php" method="post">
<?php
$server = mysql_connect ('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_select_db("database", $server);

$question = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Questions`;");
$x = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($question))
{
   echo $row['question'] . '<br />';
   echo '<input type="radio" name="a'.$x.'" value=1 />' .$row['answer1'] . '<br />';
   echo '<input type="radio" name="a'.$x.'" value=2 />' .$row['answer2'] . '<br />';
   echo '<input type="radio" name="a'.$x.'" value=3 />' .$row['answer3'] . '<br />';
   echo '<input type="radio" name="a'.$x.'" value=4 />' .$row['answer4'] . '<br />';
   $x = $x + 1;

}
mysql_close($server);
?>

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
<br>
</form>
```

And the other page:

```
<?php
$server = mysql_connect ('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_select_db("database", $server);

$question = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Questions`;");
$x = 0;
$score = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($question))
{
    echo $row['question'] . '?<br />';

    $answered = $row['answer'.$_POST['a'.$x]] ;
    $correct = $row['correct'] ;

    if ($answered == $correct ) {
        $score++;
        $acolor = 'green' ;
    }
    else {
        $acolor = 'red' ;
    }

    echo 'you answered <font color=' . $acolor . '>' . $answered . '<font color=black> <br />';


    echo 'the correct answer was ' . $correct . '<br />' ;
    echo '-------------------------------------- <br />' ;

    $x = $x + 1;
}
echo 'You had a total of ' . $score . ' out of ' . $x . ' questions right!';
mysql_close($server);
?>
```

I'd like to be able to automatically mail the results when "Submit" is pressed, and then show the user the answers page (I'll add a field for the user e-mail after the last question). Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just search internet for sending mail in php and try to send. Then, if you are unable to do that ask a question. And lot of people use phpmailer for sending mail. For more info http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ and this gives you some more clarity https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

1. you are still using mysql functions. They are deprecated and should not be used. They have been discouraged for a few years now. Use mysqli or PDO and take advantage of prepared statements to protect against SQL injections.
2. You are using `SELECT * FROM questions`. You shouldn't use select all, even years ago when we were using mysql. If you had 100k or a million rows in your table, your creating a huge overhead to pull all the rows. Instead, select randomly. There is a rand function for sql queries, though some people recommend not to use it. Instead, get the count of all your records, and pick a random number, then pull just that row where the id is that number.
3. `mysql_close` is closed when the script ends anyways.
4. if the user loads the `evaluate.php` page again, it will load again. If they don't have any POST data, then it could cause errors all over the place, and lead to unexpected results. Since you have a form that sends data over POST, you need to check if POST is set on your evaluate page. If you want the page to run only if the form was submitted, then throw an error message or redirect when no POST data is found.

Plus a few other minor things, but those are the major ones I noticed off the bat.

The code doesn't look like it would even work. So is this half "pseudo code" or actually what your trying to use?

**Answer:**
As for answering your question, you can use PHP's built in mail function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

You have everything you need where you echo the user's score at the end of your evaluate.php file. Call the mail function there to send an email saying whatever you want, like giving them their score. I am assuming you have their email address already? So you would pull it from their user record in the database. If you don't, then you need to show another form asking for their email address on the evaluate page under their score. When they submit that, call mail() and email the score to them.

I personally don't use the built in mail function. I use PHPMailer, which allows you to use an SMTP email account (created on your server for example). This will allow you to use SPF and DKIM validation on your outgoing emails. Places like Yahoo *reject* emails if they fail SPF and/or DKIM checks! So to do this, you would need to *at least* use PHPMailer, or an alternative way to use SMTP to send your emails. And ensure SPF and DKIM are setup on the email, and validate using online checkers. If you don't, you can still send emails, but your will be going into the spam folder a lot. No, there is no way to force yourself to land in the inbox. You can only increase your chances.

That technically answers your question. Now, as for a better solution to sending an email, I would use SendGrid or Mailgun or something. It is like using Aweber or GetResponse, only you can control the lists and send emails from your server through them. For for a test environment, or a site just starting out, you could mail off the server for small traffic. You would want to scale up to a better emailing solution if it starts getting used a lot.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I did answer his question. He asked how to send an email. This question has been asked numerous times. If he wants to know how to send an email, look up how to send an email. It shouldn't be hard to drop that in where he WANTS that email to be sent. He shouldn't need someone to write the code for him.  - mail() would suffice and answer is question because he did not ask, what is the best way to send the email, he just asked HOW to do it. He would obviously put the mail() function in the SAME PLACE he echo's the person's score! He has everything he needs, other than mail().

Comment: Plus - If nobody points out something like "We stopped using mysql years ago", then how would he know? If I was using something a decade past it's expiration date, I would want someone to let me in too. Maybe he doesn't have any good resources to "stay up to date" or "in the loop" and followed a tutorial written in 2002. - I was not rude in pointing out the large problems, and was rather polite in my lengthy response to his question. I at least spent 20 minutes of my time to try and help him...